# Confusing JavaScript statement about string Concatenation

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was developing a node.js site and I made a copy and paste error that resulted in the following line (simplified for this question):

```
var x = "hi" + + "mom"
```

It doesn't crash and x = NaN. Now that i have fixed this bug, I am curious what is going on here, since if I remove the space between the + signs I get an error (SyntaxError: invalid increment operand)

**My Question is : Can some explain to me what is going on in the statement and how nothing (a space between the + signs) changes this from an error to a NaN?**

PS. I am not sure if this should go here or programers.stackoverflow.com. Let me know if I posted on the wrong site.

Comment: In Firefox this results to `"hiNaN"`, which is reasonable.

Comment: My complete guess is the whitespace is interpreted as 0 or something?
----
scratch that.
Its the result of "hi" + (+ "mom")
I guess (+ "mom") is interpreted as positive "mom" and therefore NaN.

Comment: @Sirko Thank you for your quick response. The fact that it is coming back as NaN (or "hiNaN") is reasonable. I am just curious how is it getting to NaN instead of crashing. What javascript quark is this doing?

Comment: @AlexeyLebedev Thank you for answering, but could you explain your comment a little more please?

Comment: In `a + + b`, you have the addition operator and the unary `+` operator. More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's being interpreted like this:

```
var x = "hi" + (+"mom")
```

The prefix `+` tries to coerce the string to a number. `Number('mom')` is `NaN`, so `+'mom'` is also `NaN`.

Comment: *"parseFloat('mom') is NaN, so +'mom' is also NaN."* Rather *"Number('mom') is NaN, so +'mom' is also NaN."* Because `parseFloat('5foo')` is `5`, but `+'5foo'` is still `NaN`.